# How can I prove that the radius of the nine-point circle is half of the radius of the triangle's circumcircle?

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

I'm currently stuck on how do I start this proof? I know that the Euler Line exists but I don't know how to continue this proof. [image: picture of triangle]

Answer (score 0):

For instance, since $\Delta O_1O_2O_3$ is half the size of $\Delta ABC$.

Comment: I think I see it, since O2 is the radius of the 9-pt-circle and is the midpoint of the orthocenter and the vertex and that would be the radius of the circumcircle of triangle ABC? I'm not too sure if thats the right way to say it- how do I prove that O2 is the radius of the 9-pt-circle? Could you help me out?

Comment: I'm also given this piece of information "In any Δ ABC , the circumcentre S, the centroid G, the orthocentre H, and the centre
of the 9-point circle N, are collinear. Moreover, GH =2GS and SN = NH." I don't know how to continue

Comment: @John Chen: The triangle $O_1O_2O_3$ is obtained from $ABC$ by a homothety of center $H$ and factor $1/2$. So everything gets transformed. The center of the circumscribed circle for the triangle will be the transformation of the center, that is the midpoint of the segment $HO$.  And the radius is $1/2$ of that.